# No scroll javascript causes not working text input ? iPhone Web App

Tags: javascript, iphone, web-applications, text, input

I have an iPhone web app, and i use this Javascript to make scrolling or selecting things impossible:

```
document.ontouchstart = function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

I just discovered this code also 'disables' an input form:

```
<input type="text" />
```

Well.. It is there, but when you tap it, there is no keyboard popping up..

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best option would be to do something like

```
document.ontouchstart = function(e){
  if(e.target.type == 'text'){

  }
  else {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

Detect if the event target is a text input.

Comment: @eds1999 Don't worry about it we all have brain farts from time to time :) cheers!